# "I'm used to him being away " or "I'm used to his being away"

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure "Being away" is a present participle or a gerund ? If it's a gerund , according to the rule "possessive before gerund" ,then   "I'm used to his being away" should be correct.
Am i right ?

Comment: Think this way - *I'm used to his absence (being away).*

Comment: Before I checked anything, I thought, "*I'm used to him being away* sounds more natural". After I tried to analyzed the sentence, I thought, "Probably, *his being away* is more correct." So I checked Google Ngram, and I got [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+to+him+being%2Cused+to+his+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20to%20him%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20to%20his%20being%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Similar: *[in spite of him/his](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71856)* at EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking either cases may be correct:
1.  I saw him doing the job.
2.  Despite his being away I did it.
In our case the gerund (the noun form of the verb in its progressive form) is more appropriate.
As a result, using a verb as a noun, it becomes possessive.
The phrase should read: "I’m used to his being away”.