# Why use verb-ing in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure, complements

Take a look on this sentence.

> Today 71 years ago US dropped a nuclear bomb on Hiroshima killing over 1000000

Why in this sentence it uses *killing*, is it a noun and "Hiroshima killing over 1000000" is the noun phrase complement for this sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [noun phrase complement](https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/complements/) is something that is linked to a noun using the verb **be**, for example:

> Time **is** a great healer.

**time** is the subject and **a great healer** is the noun phrase complement.

Looking at your sentence, there is no **be**, so **killing over 1000000** is not a noun phrase complement.

**killing over 100000** is actually a [participle clause](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses). It is nonessential information, and should really be separated from the main clause with a comma:

> Today 71 years ago US dropped a nuclear bomb on Hiroshima, killing over 1000000

Comment: +1 . .. I commend to your attention the Cambridge Grammar's term *supplement*, which avoids suggesting that the information provided in these syntactically subordinate adjuncts is unimportant.

Comment: I'm wondering hows about this stentence: `I'm the one seeing the rainbow` ,`Here are 13 examples of Donald Trumps being racist` so what are the role of `seeing` and `being` here? Is it a participle clause or noun phase?

Comment: Gerunds act like nouns, participles act like adjectives. "I am the one [that is] seeing the rainbow" - participle, because it is following an omitted **is**, so it must be adjectival. "Here are 13 examples of Donald Trump's being racist" - gerund, because "Trump's" is a possessive, so it must be followed by a noun.  Here is a similar question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/im-used-to-him-being-away-or-im-used-to-his-being-away