# Why is the possessive used instead of objective case in "agree to your being"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, possessives

> The governors would, of course, agree to ***your being*** admittedly
> pensioned.

I could not understand the use of "your being" here; why does this sentence construction used here?
(As I've often read that preposition takes objective case but here your is a possessive case)

Comment: The quote, from the wonderful 'Goodbye Mr Chips', actually uses the word  "adequately", not "admittedly". "Your being adequately pensioned" is not a genitive (possessive) NP, but a non-finite clause as complement to the prep "to". "Your" can be replaced by "you" with no change of meaning.

Comment: @BillJ The pronoun here is in fact possessive, [as it should be with gerunds](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/022205posscasegerunds.htm) (and it is a common **mistake** to interprete it as a non-finite clause and use the non-possessive pronoun here). "Being pensioned" is a gerund, not a clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I'm used to him being away " or "I'm used to his being away".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/im-used-to-him-being-away-or-im-used-to-his-being-away) It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to refer *to **your** being pensioned* or *to **you** being pensioned*. But I have no idea what "**admittedly** pensioned" might mean here (I assume "pensioned" means "given an occupational pension", but even that seems like unusual phrasing here).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence here is a common structure used in English.
Here, "*your being admittedly pensioned*" is referring to a quality of yours; a kind of *pensioned-ness* that you have. If the governors would agree to *your being pensioned*, that means that they would, essentially, give you the attribute of *pensioned-ness*. In other words, they would give you pension.